# my app is not showing in google apps g suite marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

we are developer of collavate app and it shows as GAM pending in my developer console for more than 8 hours now so it's not showing on g suite marketplace.

Published
GAM: Pending

can you please fix this to change as approved and list on g suite marketplace?

Comment: You might want to check this - [G Suite Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172981?hl=en&ref_topic=1056394). It stated that " Most apps are available immediately after deployment. In some cases, there may be a delay of up to 24 hours before the application is displayed." Hope this helps.

Comment: still pending status. :(

Comment: Hi, @HarryJung! Was there any luck publishing your app? In help it said that app could be in review up to a week, but I having this status for the 3rd week already :(

Comment: @outring, were you lucky? I'm in a similar situation now...

Comment: @PabloDiaz, we got in touch with the support, they tried to find out what's wrong for the whole month, in the end, their developers contacted us and told that we have wrong Universal Navigation Link and we should resubmit our app with the right one. We still didn't do that, but a few days ago I found out that our app is now publicly available in the Marketplace. Weird. Just contact them at cws-developer-support@google.com and hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @outring. We just noticed that our app is available, even though it still shows as "GAM pending", which is very weird. I'll contact them just in case.

Comment: Np, @PabloDiaz. Don’t forget to check it in incognito mode also

Comment: Cool, looks like it took about a week but we're published now. A bit confusing since there was no notice, and I know we have users but they're not registering as users...